# Connected to Access Point but no internet connection?

Tags: wireless, networking

I am trying to use my school's WPA Enterprise network to access the internet with my Three-OS laptop. I currently have Windows7, Ubuntu11.10 and Backtrack5 installed.

- I can use my home's WPA2 network without any issues with the 3 OS.
- I can successfully connect to my school's network with the 3 OS but I can only browse the internet with windows7. Ubuntu network-manager and Backtrack WICD both say that I am connected to the Acces Point but I cannot browse the internet.
- I have tried uninstalling network-manager and installing WICD but it did not solve the problem.
- Every time I connect to the Access Point, I am able to browse the internet for about 10 seconds.
- I have tried disabling IPV6
- I have tried changing DNS.

Answer (score 2):

My instinct says that you should check if you have to configure a proxy in your Ubuntu Browser. Maybe there's a config in your school's network that sends an automatic proxy configuration to your browser, and your ubuntu browser is not receiving it. Check it with the network administrator. If it's not the case...

Try do diagnose your problem following this steps:

1) Connect to the wireless network

2) Check your IP address with "ifconfig"

3) Check if your gateway is set correctly with "route -n"

4) Try to ping your gateway. Is it working?

5) Try to ping an internet IP like google: "ping 74.125.234.115"

6) Try to resolve names with "nslookup www.google.com" for example.

7) Try to traceroute to an IP or name on internet. Check the result to see the last hop you reached.

8) If you passed all those tests, try this: "telnet www.google.com 80"

If everything works, but not the test #8, your problem could be related to some proxy configuration. Please, update your question with any relevant information.

Regards